# Android Wear Virtual Device - Insufficient Storage Issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtual-machine, wear-os

When creating an Android Wear Virtual Device in Android Studio, and launching, the device is automatically installing all the associated apps from my physical phone (cabled). The problem is, the storage space becomes filled and I can no longer deploy my app from Android Studio.

I've tried adjusting the VD settings increasing the storage to 5GB and the "SD card" to 5GB with no success, and I can't seem to find anyone else thats experienced this issue. Below I've copied the settings of this VD.

Strangely, the SD card is listed as 1G in the settings below, whereas its listed as 5GB in the Android Studio settings.

All help greatly appreciated.

*Android Studio Deploy Error:*

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.nybblemouse.datalayerdatamap
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

*VD Config:*

```
 Name: Android_Wear_Round_API_21_2_-_Armeabi
 CPU/ABI: Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a)
 Path: /Users/chris/.android/avd/Android_Wear_Round_API_21_2_-_Armeabi.avd
 Target: Android 5.0.1 (API level 21)
 Skin: AndroidWearRound
 SD Card: 1G
 Snapshot: no
 hw.lcd.density: 240
 hw.dPad: yes
 avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
 hw.camera.back: none
 disk.dataPartition.size: 5G
 hw.gpu.enabled: yes
 runtime.network.latency: none
 skin.dynamic: no
 hw.keyboard.lid: yes
 hw.keyboard: yes
 hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8
 runtime.network.speed: full
 hw.device.hash2: MD5:f0b5528a2769367d5624a75b0c789fe4
 hw.ramSize: 512
 tag.id: android-wear
 tag.display: Android Wear
 hw.sdCard: yes
 hw.device.manufacturer: Google
 hw.mainKeys: yes
 hw.accelerometer: yes
 hw.trackBall: no
 hw.device.name: wear_round
 hw.battery: yes
 hw.sensors.proximity: yes
 AvdId: Android_Wear_Round_API_21_2_-_Armeabi
 hw.sensors.orientation: yes
 hw.audioInput: yes
 hw.camera.front: none
 hw.gps: yes
 avd.ini.displayname: Android Wear Round API 21 2 - Armeabi
 snapshot.present: no
 vm.heapSize: 32
 runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

*File storage listing on device:*

```
Chris-MacBook:DataLayerDataMap chris$ adb -s emulator-5554  shell df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   242.9M    24.0K   242.8M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         242.9M    12.0K   242.9M   4096
/mnt/asec              242.9M     0.0K   242.9M   4096
/mnt/obb               242.9M     0.0K   242.9M   4096
/system                541.3M   333.9M   207.5M   4096
/data                  541.3M   539.6M     1.8M   4096
/cache                  65.0M     4.0M    60.9M   4096
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard     5.0G    22.0K     5.0G   2048
/storage/sdcard          5.0G    22.0K     5.0G   2048
```

Comment: I've decided that this must be a bug with Android Studio, although I can't find any existing record of it. I've actually had to acquire another physical android device, wipe, root & flash it to Android v4.4 just so I can develop without roadblock.

Comment: Try square watch. same worked for me.